# Changing a negatve number to a positive not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take a user's input and check if it is positive or negative. If its negative I want to make it positive, if it's already positive I just want to leave it. Then I want to display it.

CSS:

```
h1, h2, textarea, button, div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Positive Converter</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <h2 id="convertedNumberDisplay"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="txtnum"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="convertTheNumber()">Convert to Positive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var numbr = document.getElementById("txtnum").innerText;
var negNumbr = parseFloat(numbr) * -1
function convertTheNumber() {
    if (parseFloat(numbr) < 0) {
        document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(negNumbr);
    } else {
         document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(numbr);
    }
}
```

When I click the button to display the number, it displays NaN.
I've tried some things such as changing function names to see if that helped. (I had a problem when naming a function click in another project) However, nothing did work.
There are also no errors in the chrome inspect element debugging tool.

Comment: [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) would do this for you without the need for the `< 0` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, your `numbr` (and `negNumbr`) variable is initialized immediately, not when the function is run.

Also: You read the `innerText` of the textarea, but you should use the textarea's `value`-property.

I've fixed both these issues below, and it now works.

```js
function convertTheNumber() {
  var numbr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtnum").value);
  var negNumbr = -numbr
  if (parseFloat(numbr) < 0) {
    document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(negNumbr);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(numbr);
  }
}
```

```css
h1, h2, textarea, button, div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Positive Converter</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <h2 id="convertedNumberDisplay"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="txtnum"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="convertTheNumber()">Convert to Positive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### I'd like to add a slightly "optimized" or shortened version.

```js
function showAbsoluteValue() {
  const absoluteValue = Math.abs( parseFloat( document.getElementById("txtnum").value ) )
  document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = absoluteValue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Absolute value: <span id="convertedNumberDisplay"></span></h1>
<textarea id="txtnum"></textarea>
<button onclick="showAbsoluteValue()">Show absolute value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `textarea` has a `value` property you should use, instead of `innerText`.

On top of that, you should only retrieve the value when clicking the button, so move that part into the `convertTheNumber` function.

```js
        function convertTheNumber() {
            var numbr = document.getElementById("txtnum").value;
            var negNumbr = parseFloat(numbr) * -1
            if (parseFloat(numbr) < 0) {
                document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(negNumbr);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("convertedNumberDisplay").innerText = parseFloat(numbr);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Positive Converter</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <h2 id="convertedNumberDisplay"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="txtnum"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="convertTheNumber()">Convert to Positive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `Math.abs` instead

```js
const txtnum = document.getElementById('txtnum'),
  convertedNumberDisplay = document.getElementById('convertedNumberDisplay');

function convertTheNumber() {
  const number = +txtnum.value;
  convertedNumberDisplay.textContent = isNaN(number) ? '' : Math.abs(number);
}
```

```css
h1,
h2,
textarea,
button,
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Positive Converter</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 id="convertedNumberDisplay"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="txtnum"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="convertTheNumber()">Convert to Positive</button>
  </div>
</div>
```